# How To make computer joined AD to have a different wallpaper from the rest

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy

All of my server are joined AD (Windows Server 2012) but i want every server wallpaper to be different from other, because i have put GPO for all user to have same desktop, every time login it has same wallpaper.

so i want server to have different wallpaper even though the login is AD login

Are there any way to change the wallpaper on server to have it's own wallpaper, so whatever the login is the wallpaper is always it, not changed because GPO user policy

Because the GPO on computer (not user policy) not having desktop menu like user policy, and please do not say the server to not join domain

Answer (score 1):

Create a new GPO with the setting you want and then link that GPO to the OU the server is in.  Set the GPO to have the highest precedence.  This will not work if you have your users in the same container as your server.

Comment: I need to add that since the wallpaper setting is a user setting, the GPO targeted at the server's OU also needs to ensure that [loopback processing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978513.aspx) is set to "Replace"